# GitHub Pages: Changing User site to a Project site

Tags: git, github, jekyll

Last year, I set up my blog as a GitHub Pages "user site" per [GitHub Pages' instructions](https://pages.github.com/) in a repo following their naming convention `username.github.io`. However, now I'm working on a different site that I would like to be in the `username.github.io` repo and then move the old blog into a new repo that will be a "project site" that will still be accessible via `username.github.io/project_name`.

Is this just a matter of renaming my repo? Or is there something else I should be doing to ensure a smooth transition? I wasn't able to find any docs or other posts about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to changing the repo name, you will need to change the branch name as well. User sites are picked up from the `master` branch, while project sites are picked up from the `gh-pages` branch (naturally, because `master` is already occupied by the project itself).

Answer (score 0):

To add onto fjarri's answer, I want to describe what you should do if your former GitHub Pages [User/Organization Page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user--organization-pages) repo was using a CNAME file to redirect your GitHub domain (i.e. `your_username.github.io`) to a custom domain name (e.g., `example.com`) and how this interacts with a [Project Page(s)](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages).

---

## 1) In the Project Page Repo (formerly your User/Organization Page Repo)

**Step 1:** Ensure the CNAME file has been removed from the `master` *and* the new `gh-pages` branches.

> **Why?** GitHub Pages Project Pages use whatever domain is used by your GitHub Pages project site. So if your user site is using a CNAME file containing `example.com`, then your project site will appear under `example.com/project_repo_name`. If you aren't using a CNAME file in your user site, your project site is accessible via `your_username.github.io/project_repo_name`
>
> ***Note:** even if you have a CNAME file in your User/Organization Page repo, the URL in the settings of your Project Page will still display `your_username.github.io` -- Worry not! It will still display under your custom domain.*

**Step 2:** To ensure Step 1 worked, go to the project site repo's settings page and under the GitHub Pages heading, you should see something like "Your site is published at `http://your_username.github.io/project_repo_name`".

---

## 2) In the new User/Organization Page Repo

Follow the [GitHub Page's documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-cname-file-to-your-repository/) used to initially set up your CNAME file

> **Why?** Because their docs are good